# Windows Application Packaging Project With Admin Rights Project

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-6.0, msix

I have a project that needs admin rights to run. It uses an `HTTP listener` that otherwise throws an exception.

In my Project I added this line so it will be started with Admin rights:

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

Now when I start the `WAPP` I get an error message, which is covered in this link, [error info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh972445(v=vs.140)?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.debug.error.app_activation_failure)%26rd%3Dtrue)

If I set the `authorization` back to standard, the project starts without problems. The question now is, how can I start the `WAPP` with admin rights?

WAPP: [WAAP here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)

Error Message is this:

[image]

I have looked at the manifest file of the `WAPP`, but I have not found an area where I can set these permissions. I also deleted all the build folders as described in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these [restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to the manifest file:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust">
<rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation">
```